# Cant find cursor coordinates

Tags: c++, graphics, cursor, drawing, picturebox

im completing a drawing app where the user draws in a pictureBox. Everything is completed, but I have some problems with finding the cursor position.

here is the code/command to find the coordinates of the cursor location.

```
PointF ^newPositionX = PointF(e->Location.X);

PointF ^newPositionY = PointF(e->Location.Y);
```

It shows this error - >
error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'System::Drawing::PointF'

I tried several methods, even tried to google any sollutions, but nothing. If you answer, could you please write the code or post an external link with the code? Im not so advanced that i know what exactly to do when you write a definition.

Btw, this is the drawing line which also has a minor error->

```
g->DrawLine(pero, oldPositionX, oldPositionY, newPositionX, newPositionY);
```

Here is the error. 
error C2664: 'void System::Drawing::Graphics::DrawLine(System::Drawing::Pen ^,System::Drawing::Point,System::Drawing::Point)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'System::Drawing::PointF' to 'float'

Any help? :) TY

Comment: Why do you try to cast a single coordinate to a point ?

Comment: the drawline (pen, point1, point2) doesnt work for me .Idk why

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you're trying to initialize `PointF` with a single integer value:

```
PointF ^newPositionX = PointF(e->Location.X);
PointF ^newPositionY = PointF(e->Location.Y);
```

But point needs two coordinates to be initialized. You should do like this:

```
PointF ^newPosition = PointF(e->Location.X, e->Location.Y);
```

To draw a line:

```
g->DrawLine(pero, oldPositionX, oldPositionY, newPosition.X, newPosition.Y);
```

If `oldPosition` is represented by `PointF` too, you can simply use:

```
g->DrawLine(pero, oldPosition, newPosition);
```

For more information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawline(v=vs.110).aspx

*UPD:*

I'm not sure you need `PointF` in this case. Try to use integral `Point`:

```
Point ^oldPosition = Point(posX, posY);
Point ^newPosition = Point(e->Location.X, e->Location.Y);
g->DrawLine(pero, oldPosition, newPosition);
```

Comment: so you want me to do something like this?

Comment: like I had Drawline(pero, oldPosition, e->Location) but it didnt work somehow

Comment: Like what? Actually I'm not pretty sure about variables `oldPositionX` and `oldPositionY`. How do you declare them? UPD: yes `Drawline(pero, oldPosition, e->Location)`. What do you mean by "didnt work somehow"?

Comment: PointF oldPositionY, oldPositionX, newPositionX, newPositionY;

Comment: there was a redline under the -> ... i dont remember the exact error, but it was something similar with the coordinates of the cursor

Comment: Since you're using these variables as separated x-/y-coordinates you need to declare them as `Int32` or `Single` (depending on which overload of `DrawLine` you are using)

Comment: Hey, i solved it by changing the data type to int. Now i have the last problem with the drawline that i posted

Comment: hmmm so i changed it to this -int ^newPositionY = (e->Location.Y);

Comment: now i have just this error with the getline code that i posted in the org. question. -> IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "System::Drawing::Graphics::DrawLine" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (System::Drawing::Pen ^, System::Drawing::PointF, System::Drawing::PointF, System::Int32 ^, System::Int32 ^)
            object type is: System::Drawing::Graphics ^

Comment: Could you please show me full code of this function after your fixes?

Comment: and this is the non-intellisense error ->        error C2664: 'void System::Drawing::Graphics::DrawLine(System::Drawing::Pen ^,System::Drawing::Point,System::Drawing::Point)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'System::Drawing::PointF' to 'float'

Comment: the drawing part that i have the problem?

Comment: I suppose you haven't change data type for `oldPositionX` and `oldPositionY`

Comment: pictureBox->Image = bitmap;
   Image ^ iBitMapImage = pictureBox->InitialImage;
   Graphics ^g = Graphics::FromImage(iBitMapImage);
   if (!clear) {
    int ^newPositionX = (e->Location.X);
    int ^newPositionY = (e->Location.Y);    
    
    pero->Width = 5;
    g->DrawLine(pero, oldPositionX, oldPositionY, newPositionX, newPositionY);

    int ^oldPositionX = (e->Location.X);
    int ^oldPositionY = (e->Location.Y);
    pictureBox->Invalidate();
    pictureBox->Update();

Comment: i did change the declaratoin to int aswell

Comment: "the drawing part that i have the problem?" - it would be better if I see code of declaration and definition of all (old/new)Position(X/Y)

Comment: First, you don't need ^ symbol when declaring int. Second, oldPosition(X/Y) must be declared before DrawLine(). I'm not sure that somewhere above you don't declare them also.

Comment: Also as I can see your `oldPositionX` and `oldPositionY` are equal to `newPositionX` and `newPosotionY`

Comment: i changed that to e->Location.X/Y

Comment: the error is still the same, it needs to change the PointF to a float value

Comment: my bad :D i didnt compile it. Now its without any error. Let me test it

Comment: Well, now i have another problem. Everything just works fine, i see that the drawing data is in the RAM, but now i need to get it into the pictureBox. Do you know anything how to redirect it there?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how all this drawing stuff works. I would recommend you to google it or create another question here. And don't forget to mark this question as answered:)